# Add filter to enhanced List

Tags: apex, visualforce

We are using `<apex:enhancedList>` to show all opportunities to vf page. 
Now we want functionality to filter result by opportunity name (Please refer image) without using views.

Is there any solution for it? there is one possible solution that we can use pageblock and pagination logic to show it.

is there any other solution to filter it in enhancedList itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible using [`<apex:enhancedList>`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm). An `<apex:enhancedList>` is for:

> The list view picklist for an object, including its associated list of
>   records for the currently selected view. In standard Salesforce
>   applications this component is displayed on the main tab for a
>   particular object.

You may be able to do something with allowing them to create their own view, but I don't think it will work the way you want it to.

---

In this specific scenario, you may want to consider just using Salesforce's native built in search functionality, [Global Smart Search](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_unified_results_smart_search.htm&language=en_US). It has a bunch of other benefits as well, but this should be faster and more reliable than most manual search functionalities you may implement.

> Your search results include items and tags that you have permission to
>   view. Global search keeps track of which objects you use and how often
>   you use them, and arranges the search results accordingly. Search
>   results for the objects you use most frequently appear at the top of
>   the list. If global search doesn’t have enough information about which
>   objects you use, you see results for all objects until it has more
>   information.